# R bnlearn - parameter learning with naive.bayes() check.data() error

Tags: r, machine-learning, graph-theory, naivebayes

I have a graph structure, determined from another method, and I want to do parameter learning. The bnlearn methods, however, seem to do parameter learning directly on the dataset (strictly in a dataframe). I have two questions: how do I do parameter learning from an igraph or graphNEL structure with bnlearn?

Second question: I am getting a check.data() error when I try to do parameter learning using my dataset. Their example code works, and I can't understand why my dataset does not. See their code below and a reproducible example, below.

Here is their example code:

```
require(bnlearn)
require(Rgraphviz)
data(learning.test)
bn <- naive.bayes(learning.test, "A")
pred <- predict(bn, learning.test)
table(pred, learning.test[,"A"])
```

My reproducible example (errors on naive.bayes() call):

```
require(bnlearn, Rgraphviz)
data <- data <- matrix(sample.int(200, 61*252, TRUE), nrow=252, ncol=61)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.numeric(as.matrix(data)), ncol=ncol(data), 
        byrow=TRUE))
bn <- naive.bayes(data, names(data)[1])
```

Error message:

```
Error in check.data(data, allowed.types = discrete.data.types) : 
valid data types are:
* all variables must be unordered factors.
* all variables must be ordered factors.
* variables can be either ordered or unordered factors.
```

I do not think this error comes from detecting integers, because when I cast my data to a dataframe, I first cast it to numeric, because other methods in bnlearn require numeric or factored data. This dataset IS count data, but I want to use the method assuming I am using continuous datasets. Does this make sense?

Comment: Q1: `?as.graphAM` to see graph integration functions, including `as.bn`. You can then fit the parameters to this structure. Q2: From `?naive.bayes`: *Since bnlearn does not support networks containing both continuous and discrete variables, all variables in data must be discrete.* The note is a little out of date, as you can have mixed variables for BN's, but for naive bayes the variables should be factors

Comment: Thanks for the response! I as.bn()-ed and now it's complaining that the graph is partially directed. This is a Markov Random Field graph, so it is undirected. Can we not do parameter learning on undirected graphs? Regarding Q2, in R, are "factors" synonymous with discrete data? I'm not sure how to communicate to R that my data are factors, are discrete, or are continuous, etc. For the record, tree.bayes() also throws the same error. I'm not sure what other options I would have..

Comment: Q1. By design, bayesian networks and naive bayes models are directed (some may be partially directed but to parameterise the undirected edges need to be coerced to directed). I am not familiar with MRF's or how they should be parametised - is it enough to force some edges of the graph to be directted? Q2. the bnlearn naive models need to be factors (synonymous with discrete here) - one option is to discretise your data

Comment: Interesting. Have you heard about how to add a target class label (outcome variable) node to graphical models? Perhaps I can add directionality this way? I don't see the point of Markov RFs if the graphical structure just comments on variable (feature) relationships and not on their relationship to the outcome variable. Perhaps this is a feature selection thing? Or could I calculate the probability that both feature X and feature Y have enriched edge weights? Q2. How does one discretise one's data in R? I know about the factor() wrapper method, but I don't like what it does to my dataframe.

Comment: Q1. Sorry, dont know - I think some of these questions may get a better response at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions). Q2: there are various ways to discretise; you could use the `cut` function and choose breaks that are sensible to you (`x <- 1:10 ; cut(x, breaks=c(0, 3, 5, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE)`, there is also the `discretize` function in bnlearn that offers several methods.